# c++, read and write memory,

Tags: c++, readprocessmemory

so i am new to c++ (very new) , and i have been trying with this code for 7 hours,
and i dont know why its not working , its compiled fine but it look like its writing to a wrong address,i have a feeling i got something wrong, thanks.

```
      #include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
DWORD id;
HANDLE handle;
HWND wnd;

unsigned int baseadd = {0x021da060};
unsigned int ptemp;
unsigned int pointer;

unsigned  int newdata = 5000;

wnd = FindWindow(NULL, "AssaultCube");
GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd,&id);



handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,id);

ReadProcessMemory(handle,(LPVOID)baseadd,&ptemp,sizeof(ptemp),0);
pointer =ptemp + 0x384;

ReadProcessMemory(handle,(LPVOID)pointer,&ptemp,sizeof(ptemp),0);
pointer =ptemp + 0x14;

ReadProcessMemory(handle,(LPVOID)baseadd,&ptemp,sizeof(ptemp),0);
pointer =ptemp + 0x0;

cout << &pointer;                     // just to check if it was the right address , its not

WriteProcessMemory(handle,(LPVOID)pointer,&newdata,sizeof(newdata),NULL);
}
```

Comment: Some error checking might help, i.e. check that all functions you call actually succeeds, and if not then use `GetLastError` to check what the error is.

Comment: i did that on another code and all the functions worked, the pointer is not the address that i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you don't actually print the value of the `pointer` variable, instead you print its location. The address-of operator `&` returns a pointer to the variable.

Comment: yea i know that i printed the address , i knew the cureent addres of what pointer should be on cheat engine , i printed the value and it wasnot right either , i just dont know why it isnot the address i want its a 3 level pointer and i checked all the offsets and it is still a wrong address , thanks for your answer .

Comment: @mhatem I'm not sure what you want to do, but you don't modify `pointer` after all those `ReadProcessMemory` calls, you *overwrite* the variable contents every time. So the value when you print it will be the last value you write to it (`pTemp + 0`).